# How to track Single Page Applications using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Single page applications are relatively new on horizon of web applications but google have provided different ways to track the users activities in the single page application.

I need to identify how Google recommends to track the ajax based single page applications?

I've installed GA tracking code on mobile version of our website but its only tracking its home page. I need to track each and every single page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I have never done a Google Analytics SPA integration. But I believe the documentation to be spot on about the GA behavior in SPAs. Have you read their documentation? Has it not worked as expected? I'd like to know, since I'm new to SPAs and will have to make such an integration really soon.

Here's the link to their documentatin o SPA integration: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

I hope it might be of use to you.